# Extending an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am currently extending an Activity from a non "screen" class in android. I did this as I noticed that the OS was killing non-activity classes and this was causing me a few problems when my app was running for a long time. I am just wondering if this is bad practice/is likely to cause me problems further down the line? Thanks you all for your responses.

Comment: What type of problems? How did you code? I really don't think that android will just kill any class. Post your code.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly in non-Activity classes? Extending Activity is standard practice in Android.

Comment: "Activity from a non "screen" class" you talk about a background task? in this case you must work with Service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an object in an Activity Class A, then navigate to Activity B, remember that the OS may destroy Activity A at any time. In fact, there is a debug option to automatically kill activities when you navigate to another (for testing).

Once Activity A has been destroyed, any objects created will be destroyed and their memory reclaimed. If you want objects to remain after you leave Activity A, you need to save them in the Application class or perhaps a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your programm to run in background even if the application isn't in foreground anymore you should use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) instead of extending `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far, it's been useful. Just to give a little more info... I am creating a instance of a regular java class in Activity A, I then move to Activity B and don't leave that Activity fro a number of mins. When I do eventually press the back button, the object I created has been destroyed causing a null pointer exception. This does not happen if I navigate back to screen A withing say 10 mins. Extending an Activity in my regular java class does seem to fix this problem. I am just wondering if doing this is likely to have any negative repercussions?

Comment: The android OS only 'kills' applications and thus activities if memory is needed. And even then it would recreate the activity based on the savedInstanceState bundle. Please post some of your code and your log with the exception.